How to initialize an array of structs containing union in C++?
I have been struggling with initialization of an array containing struct members with union.
Let's say I have following declarations in C++
enum class FilterType { kLowPass, kAverage };
    
enum class FilterLowPassConfig {
    k1kHzLowPass = 0,
    k10kHzLowPass = 1,
    k20kHzLowPass = 2,
    k40kHzLowPass = 3
};
    
enum class FilterAverageConfig {
    kWindowSize256 = 0,
    kWindowSize128 = 1,
    kWindowSize64 = 2,
    kWindowSize32 = 3
};
    
union FilterConfig {
    FilterLowPassConfig low_pass_config;
    FilterAverageConfig average_config;
};
    
struct FilterSelect
{
    FilterType filter_type;
    FilterConfig filter_config;
};

Now I define an array:
FilterSelect filter_select[2];

Is it possible to initialize the array filter_select with brace-enclosed initializer list?

FilterSelect has a class invariant (namely that FilterType must match the type contained in the union) and therefore it shouldn't be an aggregate class at all. Write it as  a proper class with private members and constructors instead. Then you do not need aggregate-initialization either.

Side note, do NOT use untagged unions in C++, they're an undefined behavior minefield. (They're nothing like "C" unions). As the answer describes, use std::variant

@PepijnKramer This is a tagged union implementation.

The way it is currently written you can only initialize the first union member prior to C++20. You can add constructors to FilterConfig as well to be able to initialize with either type.

@user17732522 Only partially. There is no setters that will keep track of the last "set" type. And no enum value for unitialized (like std::monostate). So there is nothing to guard an invariant here. So it is all to possible to read from an unset value.

@Steve I rolled back your edit, because you should not edit the question in a way that invalidates an existing answer. Your original question did not mention C++11. You can post a new question although according to the comments here I think your best approach is probably to use boost as  AhmedAEK commented below my answer.

You can use std::variant instead of a C style union.
In modern C++ std::variant is recommended in general (see more info here), and with it you can do:
#include <variant>

enum class FilterType { kLowPass, kAverage };

enum class FilterLowPassConfig {
    k1kHzLowPass = 0,
    k10kHzLowPass = 1,
    k20kHzLowPass = 2,
    k40kHzLowPass = 3
};

enum class FilterAverageConfig {
    kWindowSize256 = 0,
    kWindowSize128 = 1,
    kWindowSize64 = 2,
    kWindowSize32 = 3
};

using FilterConfig = std::variant<FilterLowPassConfig, FilterAverageConfig>;

struct FilterSelect
{
    FilterType filter_type;
    FilterConfig filter_config;
};

int main() 
{
    [[maybe_unused]] FilterSelect filter_select[2] = 
    { { FilterType::kLowPass,  FilterLowPassConfig{FilterLowPassConfig::k1kHzLowPass}},
      { FilterType::kAverage,  FilterAverageConfig{FilterAverageConfig::kWindowSize256}} };
}

Live demo
An additional recommendation is to use std::array insread of a C style array:
#include <array>

// ...

int main() 
{
    [[maybe_unused]] std::array<FilterSelect, 2> filter_select =
    { FilterSelect{FilterType::kLowPass, FilterLowPassConfig{FilterLowPassConfig::k10kHzLowPass}},
      FilterSelect{FilterType::kLowPass, FilterLowPassConfig{FilterLowPassConfig::k10kHzLowPass}} };
}

Live demo with std::array

Thank you very much for your answer. Please can you tell me whether std::variant is part of the C++11?

@Steve no, std::variant is available only since C++17.

Ok. Do you know any solution for C++11?

Not sure. Unions are problematic. But why do you require C++11 only ? All main compilers support more recent versions for a long time.

@Steve : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35648390/tagged-union-c should work for C++11. Having said that why can't you move to C++17 or C++20?

@Steve see boost::variant or even boost::variant2, which can be used in C++11 (your types are noexcept move constructible so variant2 is perfect)
